# WITHOUT using network command lines in linux, how to know list of open ports and the process that owns them?

Tags: linux, networking, process, tcp

I want to know which ports are used by which processes in embedded-linux.
Since it is simple embedded-linux, there are no network command lines such as netstat, lsof.
(only basic command lines such as cat, cp, echo, etc exist).

A partial solution seems to be to use "cat /proc/net/tcp" and "cat /proc/net/udp" command lines.
However, **I am not sure the printed list from those command lines shows all ports in use**, and **the list does not show which process is binded to certain port**.

Any comments would be appreciated.

Comment: I think this question is better suited to [unix.se]

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You should be able to find all open ports in `/proc/net/tcp` and `/proc/net/udp`. Each of those files have an `inode` column, which can be used to find the process owning that socket.

Once you have an inode number, you can run an ls command such as `ls -l /proc/*/fd/* | grep socket:.$INODE` to find the processes using that socket. In case a process has been set up with different file descriptors for different threads, you may need to extend the command to `ls -l /proc/*/task/*/fd/* | grep socket:.$INODE` in order to find them all.

Comment: `find /proc -lname "socket:\[$INODE\]" 2> /dev/null`

Comment: worth noting ports can show up in HEX, eg: 2382 for 9090, 1F90 for 8080.

Answer (score 0):

To find the INODES for any port execute below command

```
PORT=8080;cat /proc/net/* | awk -F " " '{print $2 ":" $10 }' | grep -i `printf "%x:" $PORT` | awk -F ":" '{print "PORT=" $2 ", INODE=" $3 }'
```

Use any INODE from above command output to find associated PID as below

```
find /proc -lname "socket:\[$INODE\]" 2> /dev/null | head -n 1 | awk -F "/" '{print "PID="$3}'
```

here $INODE is the value of any INODE

In a single line command, we can check, if any port is open and associated to any PID as below

```
PORT=8080;find /proc -lname "socket:\[$(cat /proc/net/* | awk -F " " '{print $2 ":" $10 }' | grep -i `printf "%x:" $PORT` | head -n 1 | awk -F ":" '{print $3}')\]" 2> /dev/null | head -n 1 | awk -F "/" '{print "PID="$3}'
```